# Documents not showing in Shared Documents Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I go to the Documents (shared folder) there are no documents showing up in it but when I go to the site Content page it shows that there are 20 items in the Documents (shared folder).

I was editing the page yesterday and when I clicked on "Close" which I thought would close the editing box it removed all of the documents from the folder.

Can you please tell me how to get them to re-appear in the Documents folder?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a folder in the document library that they are not appearing in or is 'Shared Folder' the name of the library?

Comment: "I was editing the page yesterday " - Which page you were editing?

Comment: The Documents page- the one that currently has nothing listed under it.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you somehow changed the default view from what it was.  When in the library, click on the `Library` tab -> `Modify View`.  From there check the `Filters` section and make sure there isn't anything being filtered.

EDIT after seeing picture:

So it looks like you deleted the web part for the library.

If you do these steps you should see it again.

1. Edit the page you and click `Add a Web Part`
2. Click on `Apps` in the Categories section
3. Find your document library `Documents (shared)`
4. Click `Add`
5. Click `Stop Editing`

When you said you clicked `Close` you must have clicked it for the web part, which closes it from the page (see image below).

[image]

Closing and removing web parts are similar but not the same.  You can read about that here if you'd like.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg153557.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Is there a way I can send you a screen shot to better explain what I'm seeing?

Comment: Yes, you can submit a screenshot in your question.  Click `edit` and then you can insert an image directly from your PC.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Try that out and see if it works.